# I want to completely disable keyboard in Android for an activity

Tags: android

The first thing I did was in the onCreate(); method of my activity.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager().LayourParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

The second thing I did was in the manifest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

But both of them didn't work!
Still when I click on EditText. Keyboard APPEARS.

Before clicking Location[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyoqg.png)

After clicking [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdeWY.png)

I don't want the keyboard at the background. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

This should remove keyboard of the view currently in focus

Answer (score 0):

Implement `OnTouchListener` on your `editText` and set below properties

Hope this will help you

```
editTextEmail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int inType = editTextEmail.getInputType(); // backup the input type
        editTextEmail.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
        editTextEmail.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
        editTextEmail.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
        editTextEmail.setFocusable(true);
        editTextEmail.setCursorVisible(false);
        return true; // consume touch even
    }
});
```

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks to marking the question duplicate

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: @SIBINTHOMAS If it's worked Please accept an answer using the checkmark next to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works perfectly.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
} else {
    editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    editText.setFocusable(true);
}
```